# Upgrade Chaincode on hyperledger fabric using node sdk

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to install & upgrade a chaincode using the node-sdk from hyperledger fabric. However I seem to be missing something.

I am able to install the chaincode correctly on the peers, however I am unable to upgrade it. I am missing a transactionId of some kind

Basicly, I'd like to use the sdk to be able to do the following:

```
peer chaincode install -n mychaincode -p /path/to/chaincode -l node -v 0.0.2
```

```
peer chaincode upgrade -C mychannel -n mychaincode -l node -v 0.0.2 -c '{"Args": ["instantiate", "test"]}'
```

Using the sdk:

```
// Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
const gateway = new Gateway();
await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'xxxx' });

const client = gateway.getClient();
const peers = client.getPeersForOrg('PeerMSP');

let installResponse = await client.installChaincode({
    targets: peers,
    chaincodePath: '/path/to/chaincode',
    chaincodeId: 'mychaincode',
    chaincodeVersion: '0.0.2',
    chaincodeType: 'node',
    channelNames: ['mychannel']
});

let channel = client.getChannel('mychannel');

let upgradeResponnse = await channel.sendUpgradeProposal({
    targets: peers,
    chaincodeType: 'node',
    chaincodeId: 'mychaincode',
    chaincodeVersion: '0.0.2',
    args: ['instantiate', 'test'],
    txId: ??????? <----------------------------------
});
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, i was missing `client.newTransactionID()`.

Full example

```
// Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
const gateway = new Gateway();
await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'xxxx' });

const client = gateway.getClient();
const peers = client.getPeersForOrg('PeerMSP');

let installResponse = await client.installChaincode({
    targets: peers,
    chaincodePath: '/path/to/chaincode',
    chaincodeId: 'chaincode',
    chaincodeVersion: '0.0.2',
    chaincodeType: 'node',
    channelNames: ['mychannel']
});

let channel = client.getChannel('mychannel');

let proposalResponse = await channel.sendUpgradeProposal({
    targets: peers,
    chaincodeType: 'node',
    chaincodeId: 'chaincode',
    chaincodeVersion: '0.0.2',
    args: ['test'],
    fcn: 'instantiate',
    txId: client.newTransactionID()
});

console.log(proposalResponse);

console.log('Sending the Transaction ..');
const transactionResponse = await channel.sendTransaction({
    proposalResponses: proposalResponse[0],
    proposal: proposalResponse[1]
});

console.log(transactionResponse);
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have got a question; shouldnt there be a check whether the transaction proposal was successful before sending a transaction ?

Comment: You could add that indeed - the above piece of code is for demonstration purposes

Answer (score -2):

Whenever you upgrade a chaincode you need to change its version. I see you are using the same version `0.0.2` for both the commands. Plz change that and check.

> peer chaincode upgrade -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile
>   $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n mycc ***-v 0.0.3*** -c
>   '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200","c","300"]}' -P "AND
>   ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"

Comment: Thanks, but the version is not the issue here

Comment: did you change that?

Comment: Yes I did, I posted the answer below